# Passing php arrays variable to javascript for leaflet map

Tags: javascript, laravel, leaflet

I am trying to pass a php array that holds names and coordinates for infrastructure stored on the database. This is how I do it.

```
    $data = array();
    @endphp

    @foreach ($infrastructures as $infrastructure)
        @if ($loop->iteration)
            @php
                $name = $infrastructure->inf_name;
                $coord = $infrastructure->inf_lat.",".$infrastructure->inf_long;
                $data = $name.",". $coord;
            @endphp
        @endif
    @endforeach
```

The result of that loop is (Red Beach Seawall,1.3582,172.9266 Buota Bridge,1.3901,173.1343 Nippon Causeway,1.3399,172.9579 Maaman Kaburara,0.403,173.9217 TUC Main Road,0.2264,182)

But I want the outcome to be something like this in javascript.

```
<script>
                var infras= <?= json_encode($infras); ?>;
                var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([1.3582,172.9266], 13);
                L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
                attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
                maxZoom: 10,
                id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
                tileSize: 512,
                zoomOffset: -1,
                accessToken: enter your accesstoken here
                }).addTo(mymap);

                for (var i = 0; i < infras.length; i++){
                var marker = L.marker([infras[i][1],infras[i][2]]).addTo(mymap).bindPopup(infras[i][0]);
                }
 </script>
```

Can someone assist me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting it into an array in the controller, then pass $infras to the view

php code

```
$infras= [];

foreach ($infrastructures as $infrastructure) {
  $infras[] = [
     $infrastructure->inf_name,
     infrastructure->inf_lat.",".$infrastructure->inf_long
  ];
}
```

In the view you can render it directly into the js, you can also try @json() depending on your version of laravel, although I have had  issues with more complex json structures, and usually just use json_encode as that works.

js code

```
 var infras= <?= json_encode($infras); ?>;
```

Update as per comment

```
public function index(Request $request)     {    
     $infrastructures = $this->infrastructureRepository->all();   

     $infras= [];
    
     foreach ($infrastructures as $infrastructure) {
       $infras[] = [
          $infrastructure->inf_name,
          infrastructure->inf_lat.",".$infrastructure->inf_long
       ];
     }
     
     return view('dashboard.index', [
        'infras' => $infras,
        'infrastructures' => $infrastructures,
       ]);  
     }
}
```

Comment: This is what I have in my controller
`public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $infrastructures = $this->infrastructureRepository->all();

        return view('dashboard.index')->with('infrastructures', $infrastructures);
    }`

should I add it within that function or create a new function for it?

Comment: @TekitaaMautaake i have added example to the answer

Comment: Hi bumperbox, I might need to implode `(infras[0]);` as I need to retrieve the name, lat and long so that I can use them in the loop to display those markers. I am trying to find a solution for that but if you can think of one. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: @TekitaaMautaake you can pass both $infras and $infrastructures to the view, and use them independently

Comment: Thanks @bumperbox for your help. I am able to pass my PHP array to my javascript but I can't get the name and coordinates separately as I need to put them inside the loop to add a marker to my map. This is the results I get `[''Red Beach Seawall,1.3582,172.9266'']`. What I am trying to get is this _infras[0]_ to something like _infras[0][0]  infras[0][1]  infras[0][2]_ i.e name, lat and long. Do you know a function in js that can do that? like in PHP they use `implode() function`.

Comment: Thanks bumperbox.... problem solved. the loop in the javascript is not working so I have to change it to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

In my controller...

```
public function index(Request $request)
        {
            $infrastructures = $this->infrastructureRepository->all();
    
    
            $infras= [];
    
            foreach ($infrastructures as $infrastructure) {
              $infras[] = [
                 $infrastructure->inf_name,
                 $infrastructure->inf_lat,$infrastructure->inf_long
              ];
            }
    
            return view('dashboard.index', [
                'infras' => $infras,
                'infrastructures' => $infrastructures,
               ]);
        }
    }
```

In my index.blade.php

```
        <div id='mapid' style='width: 100%; height: 300px;'></div>
        <script>
            var infras= <?= json_encode($infras); ?>;
            var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([1.3582,172.9266], 13);
            L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
            maxZoom: 20,
            id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
            tileSize: 512,
            zoomOffset: -1,
            accessToken: 'enter your accesstoken here'
            }).addTo(mymap);

            for (var i = 0; i < infras.length; i++){
            var marker = L.marker([infras[i][1],infras[i][2]]).addTo(mymap).bindPopup(infras[i][0]);
            }
        </script>
```